Something went wrong with your request. Please try again later - at Checkout - Magento 2.3.7
Also, any change on the Magento backend like canceling the order and updating the order, or sending an email is not working.
Error message for above issue & Sign up : "An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details."
The error message while placing an order image attached below.
But the inventory is getting reduced each time when i try to place the order.


That is the common error message displayed to the customer, it doesn't give enough details to know the issue. Check the log and post the error message.

Please share your logs so that we can track this error.

-> That issue is connected to after place order event,
if any error in occur in after place order observer at that time inventory reduce or order also placed but the redirection is not going to the order success page So, Please check in your customisation first and if I would like to debug first you have to use this command
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento c:f
And check again the logs
